# MalformedJsonException if backslash is entered

Tags: json, types, gson, token

I am mapping 2 strings to bean class , String containing **backslash** i.e. str2 is throwing `MalformedJsonException` and this is coming only in case of backslash.

```
String   str1="logger":"mylogger","level":"INFO","message":"ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg";

String   str2="logger":"mylogger","level":"INFO","message":"ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg\";

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<LoggerBean>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<LoggerBean> myList = new Gson().fromJson(dataList,                            
listType);
```

Kindly tell me why it's failing for backslash and how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Your strings aren't valid java. Can you correct this?

Answer (score 0):

First: `str1` and `str2` are not valid JSON and not valid strings. A JSON must start with a `{` or a `[`. Quotes needs to be escaped

Second: to get a \ you must specify \ into string

Third: Gson uses '\\' as char to understand that an escaping is starting (I need to check if it's JSON requirement) so you need four \ to get one into your deserialization.

With code is:

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q23731045 {

    private static class LoggerBean{
        String logger;
        String level;
        String message;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "LoggerBean [logger=" + logger + ", level=" + level + ", message=" + message + "]";
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String   str1="{\"logger\":\"mylogger\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"message\":\"ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg\"}";

        String   str2="{\"logger\":\"mylogger\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"message\":\"ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg\\\\\"}";

        LoggerBean b1 = new Gson().fromJson(str1, LoggerBean.class);
        LoggerBean b2 = new Gson().fromJson(str2, LoggerBean.class);

        String s = "c:\f";

        System.out.println(b1);
        System.out.println(b2);

    }

}
```

and this is the result:

```
LoggerBean [logger=mylogger, level=INFO, message=ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg]
LoggerBean [logger=mylogger, level=INFO, message=ajaxAsyncGet:url:/worklist/getSearch/fg\]
```

Comment: These strings are coming in JSON format from ajax call as I am using Log4JS for client side logging.and exception is coming when it is trying to map in ArrayList of LoggerBean .This exception is coming for [ ] % \ ? symbols

Comment: I resolved this issue by sending data as post instead of get.